# C# and SQL System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

I am attempting to create an application which connects to a database using sql and I am trying to create a dataview which looks at the current selected dataview and then pulls back information from another table. I have followed some guides and have gotten fairly close but I am currently getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Index was out of
>   range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. (Visual Studio shows the error at the end of the first line below)

```
string PersonID = Grid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
sqlDataAdapter2.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from Personal_Emails where PersonID=" + PersonID;
sqlDataAdapter2.Fill(dataSet21.Personal_Emails);
```

Comment: Do you have any selected rows, and do they have cells?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like either `SelectedRows` or `Cells` has 0 elements.

Comment: What is the value you are expecting from `Grid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();`? Does Grid1 has any rows?

Comment: I don't have anything selected, the exception appears whenever I try to start the program. It has rows yes.

Comment: If you have nothing selected then `SelectedRows` will be empty so `SelectedRows[0]` will give you that error.

Comment: @DavidG I have checked and upon launching the application, the first cell that is selected is "PersonID" and it has 6 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that `SelectedRows` & `Cells` have a selected value? You could use the debugger and see what the values are.

Also:

You are defining PersonID as a string. Is it a string value in your database? If so, have you tried:

```
sqlDataAdapter2.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Personal_Emails WHERE PersonID='" + PersonID + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if something exists before you can use it.

```
var selectedRow = Grid1.SelectedRows[0];
var cell = selectedRow == null ? false : selectedRow.Cells.Any();
var personID = (cell) ? Grid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() : "";

if(!string.isNullOrEmpty(personID)
    // do query stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string PersonID = Grid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

verify if this line is returning some value <> null.

example : if the grid has no selected rows it will return error or empty value.